# How do you know if something is in an array or not in python?

Tags: python, arrays

If I have something like:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Then how do I check if 1 is in the first, second, or third array?

I want it to be able to make an expression such as:

```
if 1 is in list 1:

   do something

elif i is in list 2:

   do something

else: 

   do something
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this code? This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `any`:

```
any(1 in sub for sub in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

---

```
>>> list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> any(1 in sub for sub in list)
True
>>> any(10 in sub for sub in list)
False
>>> any(7 in sub for sub in list)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know the contents of the list, you can use

```
if 1 in list[0]:
    do_something()
elif 1 in list[1]:
    do_something_else()
else: # 1 is in list[2]
    do_something_different()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I know it's just an example, but don't use `list` as a variable in Python. It is a keyword/built-in function.

Second: you can use iteration to accomplish this. You can iterate through the members of a `list` (or any iterable object, or any iterator) like this:

```
for item in L:
    # do something with item
```

You can keep track of the number of times you have entered the loop using the `enumerate` function. The `enumerate` function returns a two-tuple in the form of `member_index_number, member`:

```
for num,item in enumerate(L):
    # do something with num and item
```

Almost there- now you need a way to associate the above iteration with your `list` of functions. The usual way this is done in python is with a dictionary, but you could also just use a list.

```
# list way
funcs_list = [f1, f2, f3]
for num,item in enumerate(L):
    if 1 in item:
        funcs_list[funcs_list.index(num)]()
        break

# dictionary way
funcs_dict = {0: f1, 1: f2, 2: f3}
for num,item in enumerate(L):
    if 1 in item:
        funcs_dict[num]()
        break
```

The dictionary method is usually preferred because it looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from ["Dive Into Python"](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html)

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
if 1 in list[0]:

   do something

elif 1 in list[1]:

   do something

else:

   do something
```

...and so on.  The `in` keyword takes a preceding value argument and returns a `true` if that value is in the proceeding `list`, `false` otherwise.  The only other thing to know is `list[0]` accesses your first element in the top level list (the first sublist) and so on, allowing it to be searched for a specific integer using the `in` keyword.

Here's the expected output:

```
>>> list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> 1 in list[0]
True
>>> 1 in list[1]
False
```

To search all lists you can use the `for` keyword to loop over your lists and `any` to return true if any of the sublists match.

```
>>> any(1 in sublist for sublist in list)
True
>>> any(42 in sublist for sublist in list)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's built-in "in" operator. This operator returns True if the item is in the iterable (list in this case), or False if it is not.

```
x_in_array = x in array
```

The Python doc that covers this is here, under section 5.6:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Your if/elif/else statements would then look like:

```
if x in array_1:
    # do something
elif x in array_2:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the index of the list:

```
>>> def idx_check(i, l):
...     for (idx, val) in enumerate(l):
...         if i in val:
...             return idx
...     return None
...

>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
>>> idx_check(1, l)
0
>>> idx_check(4, l)
1
>>> idx_check(7, l)
2
```